# Windows 10 Explorer path max. characters (Other solutions on superuser don't work)

Tags: windows-explorer, path, windows-10-v1607

I have a problem. I recently updated to Windows 10. A few days ago I recognized, that if I open a path that has more than 256 chracters it crashes.

I searched a lot in the internet for solutions and I tried a few.

I tried to fix this with gpedit.msc where I can activate the longer win32 paths. Even after a restart, it didn't worked.

I also tried it with regedit. But it didn't work either.

My Windows Version:

Windows 10 Pro (1607) 64bit

Does somebody have any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What other solutions (links, please). Did you tried https://mspoweruser.com/ntfs-260-character-windows-10/?

Comment: Use an alternative software like Total Commander or shorten the path?

Comment: Failed to reproduce your problem on my copy of Windows 10 Enterprise 1607 64-bit. Looks like a problem on your end.

Comment: My PC is in a company. I can't just change the whole filesystem. Anyway the problem could be our end-protection software.

Comment: @Hex This is the same solution as I mentioned in the text...

Comment: @CédricVoit - If you suspect your "end-protection" software is to blame, then you have to do us a favor if you want us to answer your question, verify if your problem is caused by your "end-protection" software.

Answer (score -1):

We've been fighting this since last year.  The only workaround I've come up with is to go to File Explorer | View | Options | View tab | and put a check on Always show icons, never thumbnails.

Seems to be a fix for now.  It's a VERY annoying bug that Microsoft refuses to fix.

Comment: This does not answer the author's comment.  You should edit your answer, so it specifically and in detail, answers the author's question.  Commentary should not be submitted as an answer to a question.